# wget : Измерения массива превысили поддерживаемый диапазон

Tags: git, powershell

Пытался загрузить датасет corus taiga, загружая по этим командам:

```
wget https://linghub.ru/static/Taiga/retagged_taiga.tar.gz
tar -xzvf retagged_taiga.tar.gz
```

Однако получил ошибку:

```
PS C:\Users\egor4> wget https://linghub.ru/static/Taiga/retagged_taiga.tar.gz                                           wget : Измерения массива превысили поддерживаемый диапазон.
строка:1 знак:1
+ wget https://linghub.ru/static/Taiga/retagged_taiga.tar.gz
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Invoke-WebRequest], OutOfMemoryException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.OutOfMemoryException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand
```

Windows 10 pro x64, 16GB

Comment: *"загружая по этим командам"* - это же команды для sh какого-нибудь. И при чем тут git?

Comment: `winget install -e --id JernejSimoncic.Wget`

Answer (score 1):

Команда `wget` в Powershell является синонимом `Invoke-Webrequest`, который, по умолчанию, сохраняет загруженные в оперативную память. Файл, что вы пытаетесь загрузить, содержит `92 GB` данных. Вы же в вопросе указали, что на вашем ПК установлено лишь `16 GB`, из которых Powershell может использовать еще меньше.

Для загрузки этого файла убедитесь в том, что у вас достаточно свободного места на диске, и выполните:

```
wget -OutFile path\to\file https://linghub.ru/static/Taiga/retagged_taiga.tar.gz
```

Answer (score 0):

Это команды для линукса.
Для винды нужно

- либо выполнить их в WSL,
- либо установить wget.exe и tar.exe (ищите GnuWin32)
- либо скачать файл вручную через браузер и вместо tar использовать 7z :-)

Comment: Нет, эти команды доступны в Powershell по умолчанию

Comment: @Стас - вы же сами написали, что wget в powershell - это совсем не тот wget, который в линуксе (линуксовый сохраняет в файл по умолчанию).  а оригинальный скрипт писался для линукса

Comment: @ESkri, wget это не скрипт к сожалению а полноценная утилита

Comment: @evo - слова "оригинальный скрипт" относились к двустрочнику автора вопроса (wget+tar).  очевидно, он написан для *nix-систем, а не для powershell